# Where is the default synced folder on a Windows guest?

Tags: windows, vagrant

I'm used to Vagrant mounting the current directory at `/vagrant` on Linux guests. I don't see this default behavior with Windows guests.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ferventcoder/win7pro-x64-nocm-lite"
end
```

When I SSH into the guest, it drops me in the vagrant user's home directory, but I don't see a local `vagrant` folder or anything else that looks like the workspace from the host.

```
C:\Users\vagrant>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 54CA-350D

 Directory of C:\Users\vagrant

12/08/2015  10:30 PM    <DIR>          .
12/08/2015  10:30 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/08/2015  10:30 PM    <DIR>          .oracle_jre_usage
07/12/2013  09:12 AM    <DIR>          Contacts
12/08/2015  10:31 PM    <DIR>          Desktop
07/13/2013  08:07 AM    <DIR>          Documents
07/12/2013  09:12 AM    <DIR>          Downloads
07/12/2013  09:12 AM    <DIR>          Favorites
07/12/2013  09:12 AM    <DIR>          Links
07/12/2013  09:12 AM    <DIR>          Music
07/12/2013  09:12 AM    <DIR>          Pictures
07/12/2013  09:12 AM    <DIR>          Saved Games
07/12/2013  09:12 AM    <DIR>          Searches
07/12/2013  10:28 AM               408 vagrant
07/12/2013  09:12 AM    <DIR>          Videos
               1 File(s)            408 bytes
              14 Dir(s)  33,857,839,104 bytes free
```

That odd `vagrant` file is the vagrant insecure public key. You can try this command to see the contents.

```
C:\Users\vagrant>type vagrant
```

I found nothing in `C:\` either.

```
C:\Users\vagrant>dir C:\
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 54CA-350D

 Directory of C:\

07/14/2009  03:20 AM    <DIR>          PerfLogs
12/08/2015  10:29 PM    <DIR>          Program Files
12/08/2015  10:31 PM    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
07/23/2013  05:13 PM    <DIR>          tools
07/13/2013  08:55 AM    <DIR>          Users
12/08/2015  10:23 PM    <DIR>          Windows
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  33,857,839,104 bytes free
```

I may have found another drive, but it cannot be read.

```
C:\Users\vagrant>fsutil fsinfo drives

Drives: C:\ D:\

C:\Users\vagrant>dir D:\
The device is not ready.
```

I tried several methods to explicitly sync the folder, with no luck. Someone suggested this method would sync the folder to `C:\vagrant`.

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
```

I tried various fully-rooted paths.

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "C:\\Users\\vagrant\\foo"
```

Comment: The box I'm using may be busted (https://twitter.com/sethvargo/status/674655577755267072), so I'm trying a new one (https://atlas.hashicorp.com/modernIE/boxes/w7-ie11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have paid attention to the output of the commands on the console.

> The guest operating system of the machine could not be detected!

https://twitter.com/sethvargo/status/674655577755267072

This particular box was broken and other Windows boxes worked as expected.